# .click jQuery function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've never run into this problem... can someone help me with this?

my ".click" jQuery function is not calling. I'm confident that it's my syntax, but I cannot find the mistake!

Working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cQ43Z/

HTML:

```
<a id = 'emailoff' href = "" target = "_blank">
        <img id= 'email-btn' src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/2/a/r/5/G/O/save-button-png-hi.png"/>
    </a>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#email-btn').click(function(){
                console.log('email btn clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `img` tag has an id of `save-btn` while you are attaching the click event to `email-btn`. Either you didn't post all your code or you named your button wrong.

EDIT: Now the problem is that your `a` tag is redirecting the user off the page. If you don't want that to happen then you should set the `href` attribute to `javascript:;`.

```
<a id = 'emailoff' href = "javascript:;">
```

You don't need the `target` attribute either. And unless you are using the `a` tag for something else, it is entirely unnecessary itself.

Comment: @LiamShalon If you meant to attach the click event to the div then once again the div is named `enter-btn` while your click event is being attached to `email-btn`.

Comment: @LiamShalon It's alright, everyone makes dumb mistakes. The bigger issue is that you need to spend more time trying to fix your issues before posting them on SO. I'm sure you would've caught this had you looked it over longer.

Comment: @Daniel... I just noticed that I posted the wrong html from my code... please look at it once again

Comment: @LiamShalon See my updated solution. Also, if my post correctly and sufficiently answered your question, please mark it as the correct solution by clicking the checkmark next to it.